# Подскажите, как выйти из аккаунта на сайте stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация, интерфейс

Захожу по паролю, но никак не могу найти где выход из аккаунта на сайте. Сплошные голосования, ордена, медали, рейтинги, звания, конкурсы, концерты ансамбля народных инструментов, а выход-то где? Иногда работаю с чужого компа так что нужен корректный выход из аккаунта.

Comment: [выйти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/logout) Ссылка есть в меню списка сайтов(правый верхний угол)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Нажмите на пункт меню «список всех сайтов сети» в правом верхнем углу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня нет этих полей на странице.

Comment: ну тогда уж чтобы не переспрашивать - как вставить картинку в комментарий? Я нашел только как вставить картинку из сети, а если у меня картинка на диске в виде jpg файла?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, не нужно вставлять картинки, код и вообще что-то большое в комментарии.

Comment: @insolor а где же примеры кода писать на сайте по программированию?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, в вопросах или ответах. В комментариях - нет.

Comment: @insolor Все это очень странно. Раньше я пользовался форумом RSDN.ru и там вполне себе в тело сообщения вставляли сколько хочешь примеров кода и форматирование HTML там не ручное и обсуждение удобное, тут же редактируешь код и добавляешь свои соображения. Очень было удобно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, формат сайта такой - не просто форум, а форум вопросов и ответов. Если у вас есть какой-то код в ответ на вопрос, то скорее всего это и должно быть ответом. Если у автора вопроса какое-то дополнение к вопросу, то дополнение вносится в само вопрос. В комментариях могут быть например просьбы уточнить вопрос/ответ, если что-то не понятно, ну и какое-то обсуждение проблемы.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, рекомендую для ознакомления с сайтом просмотреть [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), ну и почитать справку.

Answer (score 3):

Не первый раз уже люди про это спрашивают, на других сайтах тоже, да и на самом MSE.

Поэтому попросил их что-нибудь с этим сделать: [New members can't find logout button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314685/260198).

Comment: Ничего не сделали. Сегодня тоже еле нашел

Comment: @avp не могут нанять UX-дизайнера :D