# Анонимные вопросы

Tags: предложение, вопросы

Почему бы не ввести возможность задавать анонимные вопросы?

Иногда очень хочется спросить чего-то достаточно "глупое", что как-то стыдно такое спрашивать с аккаунта, который имеет высокую репутацию…

Например, имеешь ты авторитет в SQL разделе, но столкнулся с какой-то достаточно глупой ошибкой и не хочется подмачивать свой авторитет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите, как выйти из аккаунта на сайте stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5510/178779)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, можно выйти с аккаунта и задать вопрос от нового пользователя, но это костыль.

Comment: А почему нет? Сделать - флуд курилку. Будут вопросы второго сорта, по +1 за правильный ответ, чтобы туда мало кто заходил.

Comment: Почему костыль сразу? Выйти же просто (если знать куда тыкать:)) и задать вопрос тоже не сложно. А востребованность такого функционала, не выходя из профиля, достаточно сомнительна.

Comment: @alexolut, можно просто открыть вкладку инкогнито. И выходить никуда не надо. Здесь же можно вопросы без регистрации задавать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP тем более. Кстати, сам об этом [private mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+private+mode) пишу регулярно на MSE, но в комментах что-то забываю :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP на Мете, кстати, нельзя. Нужно сначала войти в аккаунт на основном сайте. Да и пяток репутации поднять при этом.

Comment: «не хочется подмачивать свой авторитет» — https://vk.com/wall-72495085_859623

Answer (score 8):

В вопросе главное не сложность, а качество и понятность. На SO полно простых вопросов, которые за время своего существования набрали уйму плюсов. Вот пара примеров:

- [How do I calculate square root in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9595135/4928642) +96 -5
- [What is “string[] args” in Main class for?](//stackoverflow.com/q/552796/4928642) +46 -3

И лично мне совсем не стыдно задавать простые вопросы имея кучу репутации, например:

- [Почему не работает if x % 2: --x?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/762070/178988) +3 -0
- [Как достать текст группы из совпадения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850304/178988) +2 -1
- [Как отличить ssd от hdd?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/864184/178988) +2 -0