# Скрыть свой профиль

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Хотел узнать, почему нет возможность полностью скрыть свой профиль? Как во Вконтакте, чтобы не было возможности смотреть какие вопросы/ответы делал пользователь.

Несколько причин на реализацию функционала:

1. Бывали случаи, что я задам какой-то вопрос, он не нравится какому-то пользователю и буквально в считанные секунды получаю отрицательные рейтинги на все остальные топики, которые создавал.
2. Допустим, что ты не хочешь, чтобы какой-то пользователь/компания/случайный человек вообще видели от тебя вопросы, берёшь и скрываешь профиль, чтобы при переходе в твой профиль, нельзя было посмотреть, что спрашивал/отвечал.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=blacit+site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com+inurl%3Aquestions

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Анонимные вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7756/Анонимные-вопросы)

Comment: Бывали случаи, что я дам какой-то ответ, он нравится какому-то пользователю и буквально в считанные секунды получаю положительные рейтинги на все остальные топики, которые создавал.

Comment: Но это ведь не означает, что каждый пользователь должен закрывать свой профиль, а по желанию. Конечно, такие случаи бывают, что пользователь желает пролайкать тебе профиль.

Comment: А почему можно не хотеть, *чтобы какой-то пользователь/компания/случайный человек вообще видели от тебя вопросы*, кроме как получение минусов из первого пункта?

Comment: @dIm0n Это ведь дело каждого, если он не хочет, чтобы его профиль смотрели, то почему бы и нет. Такой же вопрос могу задать и в ответ, почему человек должен хотеть, чтобы его профиль смотрели? Может, личность скрытная/стеснительная/неуверенная, вот и не желает, чтобы его профиль видели.

Comment: @Blacit здесь суть профиля участника не в выражении его мнений/ведении журнала или блога, а в сборнике вопросов/ответов участника. Если участник не уверен в своих вопросах/ответах и не готов принимать критику на них, то зачем вообще регистрироваться. Весь смысл ресурса в улучшении своих знаний и знаний сообщества в целом за счёт этого фидбека. Личную информацию/информацию о других сообществах можно не писать/скрывать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что тут не социальная сеть, а Q&A-сервис.

1. Массовые голоса за/против должны откатываться автоматически системой на следующий день.
2. Всё равно при желании можно найти. Если, конечно, сообщения анонимными не делать, но это совсем бессмыслица какая-то.

Comment: Хорошо, массовые откатятся, а 2,3 - нет. По второму пункту, тут всё зависит от желания пользователя и его пути к этому. Допустим он хочет также заминусовать пару вопросов, тогда берёт и переходит просто в профиль - это очень легко, а что, если этот профиль скрыт, то тогда придётся немного напрягаться, вбивать профиль в браузере и искать, как мне прислали ссылку выше, т.е. это уже будет ограничивать людей от тех, кто от нечего делать ставит минусы, до тех, кто не знает про такой способ с гуглом. Это только один из моментов применения.

Comment: 3 минуса уже откатятся.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так и запишем (¬‿¬ )